# Uber SDK Authorization , when tap on login button

Tags: android, ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program, uber-api

I configured Uber SDK in my app , as according to the UberRides Github documentation . When i tap on "Ride there with Uber" sdk redirect me to the login page and after putting my email and password , i get the error "There was a problem authenticating you . Please try again"on both Iphone and Android SDK as well. 
i used this code for Ride Request button

```
// Pass in a UIViewController to modally present the Ride Request Widget over
    id<UBSDKRideRequesting> behavior = [[UBSDKRideRequestViewRequestingBehavior alloc] initWithPresentingViewController: self];
    // Optional, defaults to using the user’s current location for pickup
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 37.787654 longitude: -122.402760];
    UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
    [builder setPickupLocation:location];
    UBSDKRideParameters *parameters = [builder build];
    UBSDKRideRequestButton *button = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] initWithRideParameters: parameters requestingBehavior: behavior];
    [self.view addSubview:button];  and also followed the link for intergration "https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can't offer too much help, but have you checked to make sure that you configured your app with the correct information from the [Developer Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard)? You need to set your **Client ID** and **Redirect URI** to exactly match what you have listed for your app. ([This issue might help](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/26))

Otherwise I would need to see your implementation of the `RideRequestButton`

Answer (score 0):

**Uber Android Authentication with uber SDK**

**Solved As Uber latest SKD version 0.10 Android have this "user cancel login" bug**

Please following the official link which is based on Uber SDK 0.8 where the latest one has the issue which is 0.10.

Please use sample code from below link which is 0.8 uber sdk, without "login cancel issue". Following sample for **android uber sdk is 0.8**.

https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk

Please change to this one in **Manifest file** for **LoginRedirectReceiverActivity**

```
<activity android:name=".auth.LoginRedirectReceiverActivity"

        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="com.uber.sdk.android.core.uberauth"

                android:host="redirect" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Rest is update your code with

```
client id = your_client_id

server_token = your_server_token

**redirect_uri = com.uber.sdk.android.rides.samples.uberauth://redirect**
```

https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/90#issuecomment-459646713

Happy Coding :)